# Reduce space between sections?

Tags: positioning, resume

I'm using LaTeX for my resume with the [`res`](http://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/resumes/res.cls) class. It looks great, but one detail is bugging me. I'm using the `res` class' `position` environment but the space it puts between the title and the paragraph below it is too much. Can I reduce that space?

[image]

```
\employer{{\sl \textbf{St. Louis School of Mandaue}}}
\title{High School}
\dates{June 2002 --- March 2006}
\location{\underline{Mandaue City, Cebu}}

\begin{position}

I received ``blue cards" for three years. These were tokens of recognition for good academic records of the school.
\end{position}
```

Comment: Wild guess (can't test it without a MWE): Remove the empty line after `\begin{position}`. It inserts a paragraph. If you have the above code after `\begin{document}` also remove the empty line before it.

Comment: @Martin Thanks for the info and corrections. Without the empty line then the space would become too "tight". I guess my question, phrased another way, would be how to increase the default space of `position` environment.

Comment: I know it is off-topic, but I would rather write `\dates{June 2002--March 2006}`, since the proper dash for ranges is the n-dash. Also, underlining is one of the typographical sins. Of course those are personal positions, and I mean them just as suggestions.

Comment: @rberaldo Thanks. Didn't know about the dates. I'll play around with the underlining.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not leave blank lines after `\begin{position}`. If you want to further reduce (or increase) the vertical spacing between the job information and the body of the job, then a simple redefinition of the `position` environment, as defined in res.cls, will do the job; the following code contains the necessary modification; change `-0.3em` to the value that suits your needs:

```
\documentclass{res}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{position}%
  {%
   \begingroup
     \par
       \the\tabular@head
%     \addpenalty{-\@secpenalty}% bad place for a page break
     \penalty -\@secpenalty % bad place for a page break
     \penalty 10000
     \ignorespaces%
     % change the space between the job info and the body
     \\[-0.3em]%change according to your needs
  }{%
       \the\tabular@tail
%     \addpenalty{\@secpenalty}% good place for a page break
     \penalty \@secpenalty % good place for a page break
    \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\employer{\textsl{\textbf{St. Louis School of Mandaue}}}
\title{High School}
\dates{June 2002 --- March 2006}
\location{\underline{Mandaue City, Cebu}}

\begin{position}
I received ``blue cards" for three years. These were tokens of recognition for good academic records of the school.
\end{position}

\end{document}
```